# (Java) Can I use KeyListener to input text? (inside event dispatching thread)

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm building a Swing game that is drawn entirely (everything, menus included) in single JPanel object. I have a game loop in this JPanel, which handles everything from updating the state of the game to drawing it and so on.

Now, I need to somehow enable the player to type in their own text in some of the menus. Creating a new player profile, saving some other information and the like. I can't seem to find a good way for doing this. Using a Scanner is obviously out of the question, since doing that will interrupt the event dispatching thread, freezing the game on the spot (I learned that the hard way).

I have concluded that the only way to do this is to use the KeyListener to somehow record the keys I have pressed on the keyboard. I have been experimenting with its keyTyped method, but my results have been poor. I have been able to make it record my keypresses, but the problem is, it records EVERY key I have pressed, including backspace, control, TAB, and so on... Plus, every character that I type is outputted capitalized, regardless of whether I have Caps Lock on or not.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve here. So my real question: Is there any easy way to record typing using KeyListener? Or is there some other way that can be used inside of the event dispatching thread?

Comment: is there any reason why you wouldn't just pop up a dialog for text entry?

Comment: @MrWiggles I suppose I could do that also, but at the same time I'd much prefer not to, in this case. I want to know if there is any (relatively simple) way to do it in the main thread.

Comment: The problem you're facing is that a KeyListener is exactly that - a listener for keys.  What you're more interested in is a DocumentListener.  Can you embed a JTextField within your panel as that will do all the heavy lifting for you

Comment: @MrWiggles Embedding any fields in the main panel could be tricky in my case, as that would require me to do some pretty radical changes to the main panel / game loop. Anyhow, I have decided to go with the popup dialogs at this stage. It's clearly much simpler than anything else, although not ideal. I'm facing a deadline and have more important stuff to do about my game, so I'm not going to make any drastic changes because of this. Thanks for pointing me to the DocumentListener though. I'll look into it.

Comment: I'll move my comments into an answer for anyone else coming across this issue in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are:

1. Use a standard [popup dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) and get your text that way
2. Embed a text field into your panel to receive input

The problem is that a KeyListener is just that, it listens for key events.  The standard text input components combine this with a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) for processing text